# EB client ignores config.yml file in .elasticbeanstalk folder

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, configuration-files

I'm new to using elastic beanstalk and I am trying to use `awsebcli` to deploy my flask app from command line.

The app gets deployed but for some reason none of the settings in the `config.yml` file are considered. The instance type and the service roles are all ignored.

Here is my `config.yml` file that is in the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder inside my application folder:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: anonym-app
    group_suffix: null
  master:
    environment: anonym-app
files: /opt/python/log/messages.log
global:
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
  DBSubnets: 
  ELBScheme: internal
  ELBSubnets: 
  IamInstanceProfile: StagingAnonymRole
  InstanceType: t2.small
  SecurityGroups: sg-4a984444
  ServiceRole: StagingAnonymRole
  VPCId: vpc-77cc7111
  application_name: anonymize-app
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: keypair_staging_app
  default_platform: python2.7
  default_region: us-west-2
  repository: null
  sc: null
option_settings:
  WSGIPath: application.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python: null
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently you cannot set default option settings in the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file. However, there are a few ways that you can set default option settings. You can checkout the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html) for more information.

### .ebextensions

You can use configuration files to specify default values, but beware they have the lowest level of precedence and are overridden by settings at any other level.

To use them just create the directory `.ebextensions` in the root of your project. Create a file with the extension `.config` and specify the options in there.

Example:

`.ebextensions/defaults.config`

`option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name:  Application Healthcheck URL
    value:  /health
  - namespace:  aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name:  AssociatePublicIpAddress
    value:  false
  - namespace:  aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name:  ELBScheme
    value:  internal
  - namespace:  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name:  IamInstanceProfile
    value:  StagingAnonymRole`

You can find more information on .ebextensions in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html). If you do not know the namespaces for the option settings you have you can look those up in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html) as well.

### Saved Configurations

If you configure an environment with the exact settings you want you can save the configuration and modify it to create other environments with those exact settings.

#### EB CLI

1. You can modify the current settings of your environment interactively using the command:

   ```
   eb config
   ```
2. Once you have the settings you wish to keep you can save the settings using the command:

   ```
   eb config save --cfg env-config
   ```

   This will save the environment configuration to:

   ```
   .elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/env-config.cfg.yml
   ```
3. You can save this configuration using:

   ```
   eb config put env-config
   ```
4. You can create your environment with the saved config with this command:

   ```
   eb create --cfg env-config
   ```

Currently you cannot deploy to an existing environment (eb deploy) with a saved configuration but it is supported with the [raw UpdateEnvironment API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html).